# Issue installing Hydrogen package in atom

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

i'm trying to install the hydrogen package in atom (v1.35), i don't have problems at all when i'm installing other packages but when i try to install hydrogen i got this error.

> Installing “Hydrogen@2.8.0” failed.Hide output…
>   "where git 2>nul" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>
> "dir /b /s /a:d /od "C:\Users\os.user\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit*" 2>nul" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>
> zeromq@5.1.0 install C:\Users\os.user\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11935-16244-18vhrtv.7ob8\node_modules\Hydrogen\node_modules\zeromq
>   node scripts/prebuild-install.js || (node scripts/preinstall.js && node-gyp rebuild)
>
> npm WARN deprecated @nteract/display-area@4.4.8: This package has been deprecated in favor of @nteract/outputs.
>   npm WARN deprecated @nteract/transforms@4.4.7: This package has been deprecated. Please access each transform through its own package.

does anyone possibly know what is happening?

i've tried to install from console (apm install....) and doesn't work either, i've tried to install in other pc with the same characteristics and it works.

Comment: Try reporting it on their [repo](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen)

Comment: Your output message says that the file has been deprecated.  Hence it will not work and has been replaced by another file or method.

Comment: Hydrogen has been updated. Try again...